# JS Destructuring some variables but not others on js or partial destructuring

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to destructure only the values I need and not all of them:

```
 let {myVar, _ , lastVar} = {first:"I need this", second: "Not this", third:"I also need this"}
```

Comment: Documentation for this can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: Your object has neither `myVar` nor `lastVar` properties. Are you confusing objects with arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes of course.

If you have an object such as: `{foo: 4, bar: 2}`, and only `foo` is required:

```
let { foo } = {foo: 4, bar: 2};
```

This would also work:

```
let {first: first, third: third} = {first:"I need this", second: "Not this", third:"I also need this"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

```
let { a } = { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c' }
// a is 'a'
```

or

```
let { a, ...rest } = {a: 'a', b: 'b'., c: 'c' }
// a is 'a'
// rest is { b: 'b', c: 'c' }
```

[edit - with your values]

```
let {first, third} = {first:"I need this", second: "Not this", third:"I also need this"}
// if you really want to change the variable names
let myVar = first, lastVar = third
```

Comment: @downvoter Mind adding a comment to help me improve my answer?

Comment: where's myvar and lastvar?

Comment: `{first: myVar, third: lastVar}` of course, that assumes we know what the name of the last property is. The question seems to indicate that isn't the case, but is unclear in that regard.

Comment: Sorry @KevinB , you have to destructure the object using the property names. This is just shorthand syntax `let { first } = { first: 1 }` is about the same as `let first = theObj.first`

Comment: Right. my point is the question is unclear. until it is clarified we don't know which question we should answer... we can assume that we know that the user knows the name of the key they want, but we don't know that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150847/discussion-between-zac-and-kevin-b).

Comment: the OP asks X, these two answers are answering Y.

Comment: "Is it possible to destructure only the values I need and not all of them:" I answered that question...

Answer (score 2):

You can easily rename destructured fields:

```
const o = {
  first:"I need this", 
  second: "Not this", 
  third:"I also need this"};

const {first: myVar, third: lastVar, ...rest} = o;

// 
console.log(`  myVar - ${myVar}`);
console.log(`lastVar - ${lastVar}`);
console.log(`   rest - ${JSON.stringify(rest)}`);
```